# Shiny: Switching reactive datasets with Rhandsontable and external parameters

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

Essentially, I am trying to switch between Rhandsontables that also have external widgets that manipulate them. Also, there are underlying formulae in these tables. These tables are essentially the same and the widgets and formulae work the same in both cases, I would just like to be able to switch between them. The example below may be for informative...

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

RepData1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:10)
                      ,col2 = "C1"
                      ,col3 = runif(10,0,0.023)
                      ,col4 = runif(10,0,1))
RepData2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:10)
                      ,col2 = "C2"
                      ,col3 = runif(10,0,0.023)
                      ,col4 = runif(10,0,1))

ui=fluidPage(

   sliderInput("mySlider",label="Slider", min = 0, max = 100, post  = " %", value = 50)
  ,numericInput("Total", "Total:", 500000)
  ,verbatimTextOutput("value")

  ,fluidRow(
        column(3, radioButtons("Buttn10", label="col", choices= c("C1","C2"), selected = "C1", inline = TRUE))
       ,column(6,rHandsontableOutput("hotable1"))
        )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  selData <- ""

    previous <- reactive({
    if(input$Buttn10 == "C1") { 
      if(selData == "" | selData == "C2") {
        selData <<- "C1"

        return(RepData1) 
      }
    } else {
      if(selData == "C1") {
        selData <<- "C2"

        return(RepData2) 
      }
    }

  }) 

  MyChanges <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$hotable1)){
      return(previous())

      } else if(!identical(previous(),input$hotable1)){

    mytable <- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$hotable1))

    x <- input$Total*(input$mySlider/100)


      mytable$QTY <- x*mytable$col4
      mytable
    }
  })

  output$hotable1 <-  renderRHandsontable({


                      if(is.null(MyChanges())) return()
                      df_ <- MyChanges() 

                      rhandsontable(df_, readOnly = FALSE, rowHeaders= NULL, useTypes= TRUE) %>%
                      hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) 
                    })

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

In this case, the widgets and formulae work, but not the switching...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "switching" ?

Comment: I have two dataframes in the example above that I am attempting to switch between using the radioButtons ('C1','C2') in the UI portion. The trick I'm trying to pull off here is to switch between RepData1 and RepData2, while remaining connected to the slider and total input...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  previous <- reactive({
    if(input$Buttn10 == "C1") { 
        return(RepData1) 
    }
    if(input$Buttn10 == "C2"){
        return(RepData2)
    }

  }) 

  MyChanges <- reactive({
     mytable <- previous()

     x <- input$Total*(input$mySlider/100)


     mytable$QTY <- x*mytable$col4
     mytable
  })

  output$hotable1 <-  renderRHandsontable({

  df_ <- MyChanges() 

  rhandsontable(df_, readOnly = FALSE, rowHeaders= NULL, useTypes=TRUE) %>%
       hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) 
  })

})
```

Comment: For some reason when I do that I lose my 'QTY' column and the connection to the slider and total input...

Comment: I change my anwserm, try that.

Comment: Cool! Thank you. That worked. Was the problem that I converted it to a hot_table too soon? Should that only be done in the output step if I do not want to harm reactivity?

Comment: I don't know, but for me you did some kind of loop that wasn't necessary. But I appreciated that you liked. Thank you!!